# I can't stop ProgressDialog Android

Tags: android, progressdialog

Hello, I have an Android app and in my app webview I try to make ProgressDilog. When the site is loading, in activity title every thing works great, but in progressdialog I can't stop it. This is my code:

```
mainWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {


           public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
            {
                activity.setTitle("Loading...");
                activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
                 progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");



                if(progress == 100)
                {   
                  activity.setTitle(mainWebView.getTitle());
                      progressDialog.dismiss();
                }   


            }


        });
```

but progressDialog.dismiss(); doesn't work :(

Answer (score 4):

I think you should do `PD.show()` only once, not on every `onProgressChanged()`. You have probably a dozen PDs running.

**EDIT:** To be more precise: you do `pd.show()` when you start whatever you're doing. in `onProgressChanged()` you update your progressbar with some content (percent loaded or whatever) with `setProgress()`.

Comment: You can chose my answer as the correct one by clicking the check mark ;)

Answer (score 1):

See this simple Demo which will show the ProgressDialog at every step.

```
public class AsyntaskActivity extends Activity {
 final Activity activity = this;
 private WebView webView; 
 private AlertDialog alert; 
 private Builder builder;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
     setContentView(R.layout.main);
     webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.tview);

     webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){          
         @Override         
         public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {             
             super.onLoadResource(view, url);         
         }          
         @Override         
         public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {             
             super.onPageFinished(view, url);             
             alert.setTitle("Finish Loading. . ."); 
             alert.dismiss();
         }          
         @Override         
         public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {             
             super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);             
             alert.setTitle("Start Loading. . . ");         
        }      
    });     
     webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});     
     webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");     
     builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);     
     builder.setTitle("Loading...");     
     alert=builder.create();     
     alert.show(); 
} 

@Override protected void onDestroy() {     
    super.onDestroy();  
}  
@Override protected void onPause() {     
    super.onPause(); 
}
```

}

Comment: For me this code solved. Thank you. I am not understanding correctly.

Comment: @FernandoArce no problem. Enjoy coding... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {
            activity.setTitle("Loading...");
            activity.setProgress(progress + 100);
             progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Loading...");



            if(progress == 100)
            {   
              activity.setTitle(mainWebView.getTitle());
                  progressDialog.dismiss();
            }   


        }


    });
```